# How to create autorun menu for DVD content for both Windows and MacOS?

Tags: windows, mac, dvd, autorun

I need to present HTML content on a DVD, accessible form a nice autorun menu.

Using autorun.inf is windows-only but this will need to run on both Windows and Mac, and DVD menus would be ok, but they seem to be very device-oriented. I cannot find a way to use them even for opening a .html file... (tried with DVDstyler).

How can I make such menu?

Comment: Why don't you do it slightly backwards - instead of opening a DVD and then try to open text files etc, use the auto run to start on your .HTML file (web page) and from this link to videos or the images/text?

Comment: Would do, but how do you autorun a .html page on Mac?

Comment: See this [autoplay-html-on-cd-for-windows-mac on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018398/)

Comment: @DaveRook I'm not really sure, but it seems, it offers just automatic opening files in Finder with special background image. And I need to use a mac for creating that. Isn`t DVD menu more universal?

Comment: Nah, I better update it again with .html content.. I want it interactive.

Comment: I doubt it can be done via DVD though; most DVD's are played on a DVD player which has no support for displaying text files or browsing .HTML files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6946/discussion-between-justinas-ddnas-and-dave-rook)

Comment: Did library.creativecow.net work?

Comment: No, it didn`t install properly :(
However, I found new concerns about DVD menu - that it is handled by various DVD player software, which might react to non-video content unpredictably.

Comment: It`s valid, I`d like to try it out anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2312064?start=0&tstart=0) post,

> autorun is a major security hole. It is how early malware (is) propagated. Mac OS X does not support autorun.

Not that autorun is a security hole. It's one of the most useful features of removable media and used since MS-DOS. Just goes to Apple's `Think different[ly]` campaign.

Note: According to the post, you could download a piece of software that would recognize if the device was plugged in and then do something, but I think this defeats the point.